# Question about ESTA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, esta, visa-free-entry

Can a British Citizen with ESTA get an entry stamp in the passport from a US immigration officer?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, but I wonder whether it's because you haven't said _why_ you want a stamp.  If you're trying to solve an underlying problem by getting the stamp, there may be a better solution.  (On the other hand, if your underlying problem is satisfying a desire to collect passport stamps, there probably isn't a better solution.)

Comment: I think most countries will stamp your passport if you ask nicely and explain why you need a stamp (for example, to prove that you didn't overstay in another country).

Answer (score 5):

Related: [Not stamping my foreign passport at US border](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152870/not-stamping-my-foreign-passport-at-us-border)

The US frequently doesn't stamp passports. Whether a passport is stamped or not may depend on the port of entry, whether you use one of the automated kiosks or not if available to you, immigration status/visa type, the whims of the individual officers or supervisors involved, and other inscrutable factors.

This traveler could [look up their I-94 arrival/departure record](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home), which would provide the same (and more) information as a stamp would.

Comment: "Whether a passport is stamped or not may depend on ... immigration status/visa type" which of course is known in this case.